# OAuth php oauth-api - oauth_parameters_absent=oauth_token

Tags: php, oauth

I'm a self-taught PHP developer and have never had the pleasure of diving into OAuth. I know the basics, but I can't get the implementation working.
I've looked all over the internet and stackoverflow and though most of them appear to be close to my problem, none of them work. (or I'm just missing something)

I've received a consumer token, consumer secret, access token and access token secret.

From what I understand I should use the consumer token and secret to request an access token and secret or am I wrong?

The manual I received with the tokens doesn't tell me anything besides the URL to request the data from.

I use OAuth-API from http://oauth.net/2/. I've updated the example to use my tokens and the URL I'm trying to get data from.
Currently I'm getting 'oauth_problem=parameter_absent&oauth_parameters_absent=oauth_token' as a response.

Any ideas?
If more info is needed let me know and I will edit my post.

Comment: What is the request you are making? The error message is pretty clear, whatever request you are trying to make requires a parameter named `oauth_token`, which you did not provide.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply. I've since made progress and now I have 'oauth_problem=consumer_key_unknown' as a response. So I guess I need to contact whoever manages the server to ask if there's something wrong on their end.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to add the OAuth token.
This was not included in the example and I overlooked it.